# Recursively Move All MP3's in a Directory

Tags: bash, directory, recursive

I have a lot of mp3 files located at various levels of subdirectories inside a single folder and I want to move them all to a single directory, what command could I use to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: True, it is.  Is there a way to close this myself?

Comment: You can just delete it...

Comment: @MartinvonWittich No, there's no point in answering a duplicate question. Christophe: your question will be closed as a duplicate when 2 more people come along to vote for it. You don't need to do anything. Don't delete your question: we keep duplicate questions around as search fodder.

Comment: @Gilles ah, ok. I've added my flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
shopt -s globstar
mv /old_dir/**/*.mp3 /new_dir/
```